# Navigating across URLs using selenium webdriver, python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a form to be completed and a button to be pressed on a page which would take me to another URL(post form completion) and that page has another button upon clicking which the results filled in the form will be downloaded in a well arranged pdf format. I am currently having difficulty in navigating to the second URL upon clicking the first URL's button, that is, when I try to select any second window's component, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.buttons.button-save').click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 376, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 664, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".buttons.button-save"}
```

I also tried using explicit wait before I try to click on the second page's button, but it didn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Edit :
When I took a screenshot after clicking the button on the first page and saved the image, I could only see a screenshot of the first URL. Also, I added an explicit wait to locate the presence of an element in the second URL and I got the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "button-save")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Relevant Code,

```
#Clicking the save button
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.submit.submit.submit').click()
#Waiting to click on the button in second URL
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "button-save")))
#Saving the screenshot to check in which window it is
self.driver.save_screenshot('file2.png')
#Click the button on the second page
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.buttons.button-save').click()
```

Comment: The `find_element_by_css_selector` has a selector `.buttons.button-save` passed. Are you send any such selector to be clicked? Could you show some code?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops : Sure, I will add an edit

Comment: Are you saying there are two different windows?

Comment: No, I want something like, once I click on the button in the first page, it should load the second URL in the same window and move on from first to second, just like what will happen once you submit a form.